# Implement security logic to limit access to data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement logic to restrict download access:

```
   const userPermittedFutures = {};
    
    app.get('/futures', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
        const query = {
            name: 'fetch-futures-portfolios',
            text: 'SELECT ' +
                'future.instrument.symbol ' +
                .......
                'WHERE future.exchange.name = $1',
            values: ['Futures'],
        };
        const futuresPortfolios = await pgClient.query(query).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Failed to select futures portfolios: " + err.message);
            res.status(503).send({
                status: 'fail',
                message: err.message
            });
            return;
        });
    
        let allowedFuturesAssetsForUser = futuresPortfolios.rows;
        let currentUser = initializePassport.getCurrentUser();
        let traderId = traderIdMnemonicMapping[currentUser]
    
        if (!getPermittedFuturesAssets[traderId]) {
            console.log("Couldn't find Futures contracts for " + currentUser)
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Specific Futures contracts are set for user " + currentUser);
            allowedFuturesAssetsForUser = Object.keys(getPermittedFuturesAssets[traderId]);
        }
    
        res.status(200).send(allowedFuturesAssetsForUser);
    
    });
    
    const getPermittedFuturesAssets = (traderId) => {
        if (!pgClient) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                getPermittedFuturesAssets()
            }, 1000);
            return;
        }
        const query = {
            name: 'fetch-futures-assets-permissions',
            text: 'SELECT trader_id, pair, pair_limit ' +
                'FROM common.accounts_pairs_permits app ' +
                'WHERE exists(SELECT * FROM future.instrument ap WHERE ap.symbol = app.pair) AND trader_id = $1',
            values: [traderId],
        };
        pgClient.query(query, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Can't get account permitted futures permits. Retrying in a second...");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getPermittedFuturesAssets();
                }, 1000);
                return;
            }
            for (let row of res.rows) {
                addUserFuturesConstraints(row.trader_id, row.pair, row.pair_limit);
            }
        });
    }
    
    function addUserFuturesConstraints(trading_id, futuresAsset, limit) {
        if (!userPermittedFutures[trading_id]) {
            let user_permitted_limits = {}
            user_permitted_limits[futuresAsset] = createUserFuturesAssetsConstraints(limit);
            userPermittedFutures[trading_id] = user_permitted_limits;
        } else {
            userPermittedFutures[trading_id][futuresAsset] = createUserFuturesAssetsConstraints(limit);
        }
    }
    
    function isUserAbleToTradeFutures(req, res, next) {
        if (adminUsers[req.user.username]) { // admin users can trade with all pairs without limits
            return next();
        }
        if (!isFuturesAssetAllowedForUser(req.user.username, req.body.selectedPair)) {
            return res.status(503).send({status: "Failed to execute because Futures Asset is not allowed for user."});
        }
        if (isUserFuturesLimitReached(req.user.username, req.body.amount, req.body.selectedPair)) {
            return res.status(503).send({status: "Failed to execute because the order exceeds the user's trading limit for Futures Asset."});
        }
        return next();
    }
    
    function isFuturesAssetAllowedForUser(username, selectedFutureAsset) {
        let traderId = traderIdMnemonicMapping[username];
        if (!userPermittedFutures[traderId]) {
            return false;
        }
        for (let futureAsset of Object.entries(userPermittedFutures[traderId])) {
            if (futureAsset[0] === selectedFutureAsset) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    function isUserFuturesLimitReached(username, amount, selectedFuturesAsset) {
        let traderId = traderIdMnemonicMapping[username]
        if (!userPermittedFutures[traderId][selectedFuturesAsset]) { // if limit is undefined then it is unlimited.
            return false;
        }
        return parseFloat(amount) > userPermittedFutures[traderId][selectedFuturesAsset].pairQuantityLimit;
    }
    
    function createUserFuturesAssetsConstraints(pairQuantityLimit) {
        return {
            pairQuantityLimit: parseFloat(pairQuantityLimit),
            splitConstraints: [],
        }
    }
```

But I'm stuck how to implement `createUserFuturesAssetsConstraints`.
When user tries to access endpoint and make request see should be limited to an asset for example `asset1` based on the username.

How I can implement the logic so that user can can access only a defined list of items based on his username?

Comment: Check this https://sentry.io/answers/unique-key-prop/

Comment: Short answer: Add a `key` prop to the `<option>` element.  In this case it most likely doesn't matter what value is in that prop as long as it's unique.